# Outlook web error "Failed to load LazyModule"

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

Since 2019/11/15, on every device on our network, we can sign into Office 365 and access all web apps except for Outlook on the Web / OWA which will hang for a good few minutes on the loading screen then fail with the following error:

```
Something went wrong
We can't get that information right now. Please try again later.
cId: 56AB7DD68B044885A47203B21C7724FE
app: Mail
st: undefined
reqid: undefined
wsver: undefined
efe: undefined
ebe: undefined
et: ClientError
esrc: Script
err: Error: Failed to load LazyModule
estack: Error: Failed to load LazyModule
    at e.<anonymous> (https://outlook.office365.com/mail/?bO=1&sessionId=4ecb688c-2cb4-4ab1-8b9f-2bdf8d64bff8:356:13093)
    at https://outlook.office365.com/mail/?bO=1&sessionId=4ecb688c-2cb4-4ab1-8b9f-2bdf8d64bff8:356:2489
    at Object.next (https://outlook.office365.com/mail/?bO=1&sessionId=4ecb688c-2cb4-4ab1-8b9f-2bdf8d64bff8:356:2594)
    at https://outlook.office365.com/mail/?bO=1&sessionId=4ecb688c-2cb4-4ab1-8b9f-2bdf8d64bff8:356:1532
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at d (https://outlook.office365.com/mail/?bO=1&sessionId=4ecb688c-2cb4-4ab1-8b9f-2bdf8d64bff8:356:1309)
    at e.onLoadFailed (https://outlook.office365.com/mail/?bO=1&sessionId=4ecb688c-2cb4-4ab1-8b9f-2bdf8d64bff8:356:12766)
    at e.<anonymous> (https://outlook.office365.com/mail/?bO=1&sessionId=4ecb688c-2cb4-4ab1-8b9f-2bdf8d64bff8:356:12028)
    at https://outlook.office365.com/mail/?bO=1&sessionId=4ecb688c-2cb4-4ab1-8b9f-2bdf8d64bff8:356:2489
    at Object.throw (https://outlook.office365.com/mail/
ts: 18/11/2019 09:33:51
```

[image]

The only other instances of this I've found online are as follows and none have a solution, hence this post:

- https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/322590-outlook-2016-for-windows/suggestions/36802501-issues-in-outlook-web
- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/issue-in-web-outlook/7c49a19a-28c6-4e13-9fa2-54ffb95f38a5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our Sophos XG NGFW / UTM application control had started blocking application 2539 "Microsoft Outlook". Whitelisting this resolved the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my outlook office 365 account in google Chrome, and I tried to deactivate all of the chrome extensions, and it worked again! It seems that the issue simply comes from any kind of conflict between the extensions and outlook.